# Horspool Output wrong

Tags: java, output

this is a bit of a homework problem.  I have a java program to calculate if a certain pattern/string is in a user-entered string of text.  The program works, but always outputs a -1, which is what it should output if the pattern string is not in the specified text.  I can't figure out for the life of me what isn't working, and I would be most appreciative of a hint for what I need to fix.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Mouse
 *
 */
public class horspool {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner (System.in);

    //The text to search for the phrase in
    String t = "";

    //The phrase/pattern to search for
    String p = "";

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println("Harspool's Algorithm: ");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Please enter the full text: ");
    t = scanIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the pattern to search for: ");
    p = scanIn.nextLine();

    char[] text = new char[t.length()];
    char[] pattern = new char[p.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        text[i] = t.charAt(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++)
    {
        pattern[i] = p.charAt(i);
    }

    int newChar[] = new int[256];

    for(int i=0; i < 256; i++) 
    {
        newChar[i]=0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        newChar[t.charAt(i) % 256]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++)
    {
        newChar[p.charAt(i) % 256]++;
    }

    int index = HorspoolMatching(pattern, text);

    System.out.println("Index: " + index);
}

public static int[] ShiftTable(char[] p) 
{
    int m = p.length;

    //Table filled with shift sizes for each individual letter.
    int[] table = new int[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    {
        table[i] = m;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < p.length; a++)
        {
            if (p[j] == p[a])
            {
                table[a] = (m - 1 - j);
            }
        }
    }
    return table;
}


public static int HorspoolMatching(char[] p, char[] t) 
{
    int [] table = ShiftTable(p);
    int m = p.length;
    int i = m - 1;
    int n = t.length;
    int temp = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (i <= n - 1)
    {
        k = 0;

        while (t[i - k] == p[m - 1 - k] && k < m - 1) 
        {
            System.out.println("In second while");
            k++;
        }   
        if (k == m)
        {
            return (i - m + 1);
        } 
        else
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < t.length; a++)
            {
                if (t[i] == t[a])
                {
                    temp = table[a];
                }
            }
            i = i + temp;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Use a debugger and step through a small example. Also "the program works", but "isn't working" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> It always outputs a -1

Check the return statement in HorspoolMatching.

Edit: okay, I derped, sorry.

When I changed

```
while (t[i - k] == p[m - 1 - k] && k < m - 1)
```

to

```
while ( k < m && t[i - k] == p[m - 1 - k])
```

it started working.

The problem with k < m - 1 was that you were stopping a loop too soon and never actually checking the full pattern, therefore, no match.

By moving it to the first condition of the && and removing the -1, it now checks the full pattern and the while will fail when it's supposed to: before the index goes out of bounds, rather than one loop before that.

More edits:

I'm skipping the sys in for now and set:

```
String t = "lklklklkabcdabababcd";
String p = "ab";
```

Which gives 8

But

```
String t = "lklklklkabcdabababcd";
String p = "abc";
```

is giving -1...

Okay, this should do it [spoiler alert]

```
table[i] = 1; //m;
```

Comment: I have, but there's another return statement in the method:
if (k == m)
        {
            return (i - m + 1);
        } 

The problem is it never gets into that if

Comment: Thank you!  That actually makes a lot more sense.  Weird how it was just something small like that.  I'll spend some time working to try and fix that -1 error you mentioned.